# Yet another "driver_power_state_failure" on Win8.1 (with DUMP)

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, bsod, dump, minidumps

please bear with me if I post another question on this subject, but this is starting to kill me.

Full specs of my notebook are here: http://speccy.piriform.com/results/sJx43YcJyRtL5RkopHR5YbV

I noticed frequent BSOD when on "balanced" power management or on battery power. So I enabled MiniDumps and initially I found wi-fi and basic-video driver to be implicated. So I put them on "maximum performance" while on "balanced" power and I was left with only **ntoskrnl.exe** as probable cause on the next BSOD.

Once I enabled full Memory Dumps, on WinDbg I read this after again another driver_power_state_failure:

```
************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*C:\Windows\symbol_cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17298 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Full address space is available


************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*C:\Windows\symbol_cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\Windows\symbol_cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 8 Kernel Version 9600 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 9600.17238.amd64fre.winblue_gdr.140723-2018
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`7dc07000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`7ded1350
Debug session time: Thu Apr 23 19:20:19.120 2015 (UTC + 2:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 6:35:19.836
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
.............................
Loading User Symbols

Loading unloaded module list
........
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 9F, {3, ffffe00065601730, ffffd000576ad930, ffffe00068274800}

Probably caused by : pci.sys

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

5: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe00065601730, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffffd000576ad930, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe00068274800, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

DRIVER_OBJECT: ffffe000645f69b0

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  53d0f1d4

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff80130d92000 pci

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17298 (debuggers(dbg).141024-1500) amd64fre

DPC_STACK_BASE:  FFFFD000576B4FB0

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd000`576ad8f8 fffff801`7de03586 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 ffffe000`65601730 ffffd000`576ad930 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd000`576ad900 fffff801`7de034a6 : ffffe000`69bfaf08 00000000`ffffffff ffffe000`69bfaf48 fffff801`7dc4d190 : nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck+0xde
ffffd000`576ad960 fffff801`7dc49760 : 00000000`00000000 ffffd000`576adab0 ffffe000`69bfaf40 fffff801`00000002 : nt!PopIrpWatchdog+0x32
ffffd000`576ad9b0 fffff801`7dd5e7ea : ffffd000`57683180 ffffd000`57683180 ffffd000`5768f3c0 ffffe000`639f55c0 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x4f0
ffffd000`576adc60 00000000`00000000 : ffffd000`576ae000 ffffd000`576a8000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.3.9600.17238

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_IMAGE_pci.sys

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_image_pci.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {a89ab2d1-2459-89ee-9990-558bbc68ffab}

Followup: MachineOwner
```

At this point I'm clueless on what I can do to prevent this failure (apart from staying always connected to the power grid AND on "maximum performance" on the power menagement.

Actual DUMP files here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7zqmhx3kpik2t7u/AADFyhN1Wkp0LHJ-Gba0fv-_a?dl=0

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I need the actual dmp file to see mroe details.

Comment: Ok. DUMP files here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7zqmhx3kpik2t7u/AADFyhN1Wkp0LHJ-Gba0fv-_a?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the dmp, the nVIDIA driver nvlddmkm.sys for your NVIDIA GeForce GTX 850M (VEN_10DE&DEV_1391) is the cause:

```
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffe00067c3d1f0 Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for nvlddmkm.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for nvlddmkm.sys
 \Driver\nvlddmkm   ffffe00067c3d340  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe00067c3d1c0

> ffffe00065603c10  \Driver\ACPI       ffffe000645dac90  
  ffffe00065601730  \Driver\pci        ffffe00065601880  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffe00065603070 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1391&SUBSYS_17BD1043&REV_A2\4&8bc3a2b&0&0008"
  ServiceName is "nvlddmkm"


    Loaded symbol image file: nvlddmkm.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys
    Image name: nvlddmkm.sys
    Timestamp:        Wed Nov 12 21:51:31 2014 (5463C853)
```

Try a newer [nVIDIA driver](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/83821/en-us) and also install all Updates including the optional UpdateRollups, you're at 2014 level (`9600.17238.amd64fre.winblue_gdr.140723-2018`).

Comment: Well, thanks. Didn't imagine it was the nvidia driver. I downgraded on purpose to investigate another issue (now fixed). ATM, so far so good. I'll have a look at UpdateRollups. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately... still another issue: http://superuser.com/questions/906578/still-another-driver-power-state-failure-on-win8-1-with-dump