# Still another “driver_power_state_failure” on Win8.1 (with DUMP)

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, bsod, dump, minidumps

Continuing from question [Yet another "driver_power_state_failure" on Win8.1 (with DUMP)](https://superuser.com/questions/905563/yet-another-driver-power-state-failure-on-win8-1-with-dump)

I followed advices provided, upgrading Nvidia drivers and win8.1, but unfortunately I had another BSOD on the same issue: **driver_power_state_failure**

Output from WinDbg:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17298 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\Samuele\Documents\MEMORY_27-04-2015.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Full address space is available


************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*C:\Windows\symbol_cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\Windows\symbol_cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 8 Kernel Version 9600 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 9600.17736.amd64fre.winblue_r9.150322-1500
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`56872000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`56b4b850
Debug session time: Mon Apr 27 09:29:52.197 2015 (UTC + 2:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:19:04.911
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
.............................
Loading User Symbols

Loading unloaded module list
.......
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 9F, {3, ffffe0019a5ce060, ffffd00126a5b960, ffffe0019a5ef010}

Probably caused by : pci.sys

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

4: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe0019a5ce060, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffffd00126a5b960, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe0019a5ef010, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


OVERLAPPED_MODULE: Address regions for 'srv' and 'IntcDAud.sys' overlap

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  53d0f1d4

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff800a7796000 pci

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17298 (debuggers(dbg).141024-1500) amd64fre

DPC_STACK_BASE:  FFFFD00126A62FB0

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd001`26a5b928 fffff801`56a7a782 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 ffffe001`9a5ce060 ffffd001`26a5b960 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd001`26a5b930 fffff801`56a7a6a2 : ffffe001`9a5ef838 00000000`00000001 ffffe001`9a5ef870 fffff801`56916391 : nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck+0xde
ffffd001`26a5b990 fffff801`569182d8 : 00000000`00000000 ffffd001`26a5bae0 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000002 : nt!PopIrpWatchdog+0x32
ffffd001`26a5b9e0 fffff801`569c67ea : ffffd001`2b339180 ffffd001`2b339180 ffffd001`2b3453c0 ffffe001`9e61d080 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x4f8
ffffd001`26a5bc60 00000000`00000000 : ffffd001`26a5c000 ffffd001`26a56000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.3.9600.17238

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_ACPI_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_ACPI_IMAGE_pci.sys

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_acpi_image_pci.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {20ddeb92-07eb-ebdc-bd08-44da71ffbd68}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

4: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe0019a5ce060, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffffd00126a5b960, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe0019a5ef010, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


OVERLAPPED_MODULE: Address regions for 'srv' and 'IntcDAud.sys' overlap

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  53d0f1d4

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff800a7796000 pci

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17298 (debuggers(dbg).141024-1500) amd64fre

DPC_STACK_BASE:  FFFFD00126A62FB0

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd001`26a5b928 fffff801`56a7a782 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 ffffe001`9a5ce060 ffffd001`26a5b960 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd001`26a5b930 fffff801`56a7a6a2 : ffffe001`9a5ef838 00000000`00000001 ffffe001`9a5ef870 fffff801`56916391 : nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck+0xde
ffffd001`26a5b990 fffff801`569182d8 : 00000000`00000000 ffffd001`26a5bae0 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000002 : nt!PopIrpWatchdog+0x32
ffffd001`26a5b9e0 fffff801`569c67ea : ffffd001`2b339180 ffffd001`2b339180 ffffd001`2b3453c0 ffffe001`9e61d080 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x4f8
ffffd001`26a5bc60 00000000`00000000 : ffffd001`26a5c000 ffffd001`26a56000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.3.9600.17238

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_ACPI_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_ACPI_IMAGE_pci.sys

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_acpi_image_pci.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {20ddeb92-07eb-ebdc-bd08-44da71ffbd68}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Minidump: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0s3522ojxauyea/042715-24328-01.dmp?dl=0

Comment: A forum would be a far better place IMO to discuss all these related issues in a single thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time, the `Intel PCI Express x16 Controller` (`PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0C01`) causes the crash:

```
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffe0019a5a3ba0  \Driver\pci        ffffe0019a5a3cf0  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe0019a5a3b70

> ffffe0019a5e0900  \Driver\ACPI       ffffe0019a5b6890  
  ffffe0019a5ce060  \Driver\pci        ffffe0019a5ce1b0  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffe0019a5e0400 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0C01&SUBSYS_17BD1043&REV_06\3&11583659&1&08"
  ServiceName is "pci"
```

In the power settings of Windows, disable the PCI Express power saving and look what happens.

Comment: Cool. I hope this will fix the issue. But how do you find those info; from the minidump? Is it the same driver highlighted by the **blue-screen-view** application, right? - As a further info, I was on battery, but energy saving profile was "maximum performance" and not "balanced".

Comment: I use the !podev and !devstack command: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/doronh/archive/2006/03/15/552301.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info. No problems so far, with no BSODs (I followed your advice).